# How to copy Apple Calendar Server data to a new installation?

Tags: osx-server

I have recently reinstalled my Mac Mini server. It was acting up after the upgrade from SLS to Lion Server, so I reinstalled with Lion.

I can't figure out how to properly migrate calendar data from the old installation.

I have tried copying `/Library/Server/Calendar and Contacts/` from the old installation to the new one, but that makes no difference I can see. Can anyone help me figure out how to do it?

Comment: Did you backup your OD data?

Comment: I still have the old installation on an old disk, fully bootable, so I should have backups of almost everything…

Comment: If you can do an OpenDirectory export/import or migration and then copy your Calendar and Contacts data, it should work.